# PHP for an image gallery pulled from facebook, only grabs the first 25 images

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I am realizing I have a LOT to learn about PHP.
I was wondering what am I skipping, because as the title says, my image gallery using PHP takes images from a facebook site, but only pulls the first 25 pictures everytime, and all the pictures are public and uploaded by the same person.
I am using a tutorial taken from this site:
http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/facebook-image-gallery/

And the code used specifically is this:

```
<?php

    //Set the page name or ID
    $FBid = 'ArazaArtesanias';

    //Get the contents of a Facebook page
    $FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$FBid.'/albums');

    //Interpret data with JSON
    $photoData = json_decode($FBpage);

    echo '<ul id="display-inline-block">';
    foreach ( $photoData->data as $data )

    {
        echo '<li><a href="getphotos.php?album_id='.$data->id.'">
                  <img class="shadow" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$data->id.'/picture/" width=70 border=0 />                  
                  </a>';
        echo '<br /><a href="getphotos.php?album_id='.$data->id.'">'.$data->name.'</a></li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

And for the individual albums gallery is this:

```
<?php
    //Get the contents of the album data page
    $rawAlbumData = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$_GET['album_id'].'/photos');
    //Interpret data with JSON
    $photoData = json_decode($rawAlbumData);

    echo '<ul id="display-inline-block">';
    foreach ( $photoData->data as $data )
        {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$data->source.'" rel="lightbox" title="';
                if (property_exists($data, "comments")) {
                    foreach ( $data->comments->data as $Cdata )
                        {
                            echo htmlentities('<li class="imgcomments">
                                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'"    target="_blank">                                                                             <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$Cdata->from->id.'/picture" 
                                              align=left border=0 />
                                              </a>&nbsp;
                                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'" target="_blank">
                                              <b>'.$Cdata->from->name.'</a>: </b>'.$Cdata->message.'<br />
                                              <div align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                              <small>&nbsp;Posted '.timeSince(strtotime($Cdata->created_time)).' ago</small></div>                                                   </li>');
                        }
                }
                else {
                    echo 'There are no comments on this album';
                    }
            echo '"><img class="shadow" src="'.$data->picture.'" width=70 border=0 /></a></li>';
            }


    echo '</ul>';   

    //Get data about the photo album
    $rawCommentData = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$_GET['album_id']);
    //Interpret comment data with JSON
    $commentData = json_decode($rawCommentData);

    echo '<div class="comments">';
    echo '<h2>Album Comments</h2>';

    if ( $commentData->comments->data ) {


        foreach ( $commentData->comments->data as $data )
        { 
            echo '&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$data->from->id.'" target="_blank"><b>'
                 .$data->from->name.'</a>: </b>'.$data->message.'<br/><div align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                 <small>&nbsp;Posted '.timeSince(strtotime($data->created_time)).' ago</small></div></li>';     
            }
    } 
        else {
            echo 'There are no comments on this album';
        }
    echo '</div>'; 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your PHP code; the URL you use to retrieve the JSON data only returns 25 `<data>` items (=pictures.)

Chech the Facebook API documentation on how to either retrieve more than 25 pictures in a go, or how to specify an "offset" (so that you can retrieve pictures 26-50, for example.)

Comment: As a side question which I forgot to ask before, I am trying to determine why every time I roll over an image with comments, it displays the entire html code like an img title attribute. I already tried htmlspecialchars, and changing the title attribute to the image with no luck

Comment: The problem may be invalid HTML. You have this line: `echo '<li><a href="'.$data->source.'" rel="lightbox" title="';` which starts a `title` property, and then you go on to add - for each item in the array - a HTML-escaped `<li>` tag. Neither does adding tags inside the `title` property make sense, nor does HTML-encoding them. Your browser just displays what's in the `title`: A bunch of HTML code.