# echo htmlentities image title

Tags: php, facebook

Apologies if this seems like a re-post, but earlier today I posted this question: [PHP for an image gallery pulled from facebook, only grabs the first 25 images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719657/php-for-an-image-gallery-pulled-from-facebook-only-grabs-the-first-25-images)

And I forgot to ask what I assume is a small issue.
On the echo htmlentities tag displayed here:

```
                    echo htmlentities ('<li class="imgcomments">
                                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'"    target="_blank">                                                                             
                                      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$Cdata->from->id.'/picture" 
                                      align=left border=0 />
                                      </a>&nbsp;
                                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'" target="_blank">
                                      <b>'.$Cdata->from->name.'</a>: </b>'.$Cdata->message.'<br />
                                      <div align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                      <small>&nbsp;Posted '.timeSince(strtotime($Cdata->created_time)).' ago</small></div>                                                   </li>');
```

Whenever I hover over an image with no comments, there is no issue because after this code there's an else displaying "there are no comments".
But when I hover over one that does have comments I get the same as an img title attribute but it displays the entire html code linked here.
I already gave htmlspecialchars a try and also wrapping all the html code with a span with a title=" ".

***Edit:*** I found the error, now I am seeing about ways to fix it. the problem was way before on the code:

```
    echo '<li><a href="'.$data->source.'" rel="lightbox" title="';
        if (property_exists($data, "comments")) {
            foreach ( $data->comments->data as $Cdata )
                {
                    echo htmlentities ('<li class="imgcomments">
                                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'"    target="_blank">
```

On the first line, the title attribute is making it display the entire html code, I am assuming that I'll have to resort to an if/else statement, but if anyone else has a better idea...

Comment: By this do you mean its printing all the tags as well as content? Have you tried html_entity_decode?

Comment: Also why are you using htmlentities? I'm unfamiliar with the facebook side, but I usually use that function to sanitize user input before printing to the screen etc? Is a function actually needed?

Comment: I mean it displays on the image title attribute (when I hover over the image) the entire html code linked here. I just tried replacing htmlentities with html_entity_decode and it's no good, it actually "breaks" the page.

Comment: And I am using htmlentities because I was following the tutorial linked on the other page http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/facebook-image-gallery/